# UICollectionVIew: Animate cells as the view is scrolled

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I would like items in my `UICollectionView` to animate as the user scrolls through the list.

More specifically, I would like each item to gradually flip around as it "leaves" the visible part of the scroll view.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

You probably want to use UIKit dynamics. Here is a good example: http://www.objc.io/issue-5/collection-views-and-uidynamics.html

There are some pre-set dynamic behaviours described at Apple's [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDynamicBehavior_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIDynamicBehavior),

The best choice seems to be the `UIDynamicItemBehavior`, as it has an `allowsRotation` property.

Comment: Thanks. That's a big article to read... There is also this [project](https://github.com/szk-atmosphere/SACollectionViewVerticalScalingFlowLayout) inspired by the same article.